# Escape ] Character in String

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a nested loop that I'm using to generate option form elements.  I'm trying to get my output to be

```
round_1 [
  'playername' => 'id'
]
```

I believe the code I have now is spitting out nonsense because the brackets are not being escaped when they are passed into the `<select name=...` statement.  Everything else works fine.

Is there a way to escape $player and and pass it into the array in PHP or Blade?

I've pasted the relevant chunk of my code:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'admin/games/process']) !!}

@foreach ($players_array as $game)
    <h4>Round {{$round}}</h4>
    <div class="form-group">

        @foreach($game as $player)
            <p><strong>{{ $player }}</strong></p>

            <!-- This chunk might be able to be written cleaner using laravelcollective/html -->
            <select name="round_{{$round}}[{{$player}}]">
                @foreach($all_players as $key=>$p)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $p }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

        @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- {{ $round++ }} -->

@endforeach

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Submit Refactored Players', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `str_replace`to replace the `]` character, pass that into the controller, then create a new array to place old array with the reverse replacement as you cannot reliable change the php key.

View

```
@foreach ($players_array as $game)
    <h4>Round {{$round}}</h4>
    <div class="form-group">

        @foreach($game as $player)
            <p><strong>{{ $player }}</strong></p>

            <!-- This chunk might be able to be written cleaner using laravelcollective/html -->
            <select name="round_{{$round}}[{{str_replace("]", "fstupidkey", $player)}}]">
                @foreach($all_players as $key=>$p)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $p }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

        @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- {{ $round++ }} -->

@endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function process_logs(Request $request)
{
    /*
     * Accept player match arrays from user form
     * Input event data into database
     */


    $a = $request->round_1;

    /*
    * Create new array to put shit in..
    */
    $b = [];

    foreach($a as $key=>$item)
    {
        $c = str_replace("fstupidkey", "]", $key);
        $b[$c] = $item;
    }

    dd($b);

}
```